# Multiple queues using azure service bus and spring integration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, azureservicebus

I have this scenario. I have many queues in Azure ServiceBus, the implementation below works, however it is not flexible since would need to replicate for each queue. I would like to change from dynamically forming, maybe as a parameter in the method send() the queue name and the OUTPUT_CHANNEL for @ServiceActivator and @MessagingGateway, It is possible?

```
import com.azure.spring.cloud.service.servicebus.properties.ServiceBusEntityType;
import com.azure.spring.integration.core.handler.DefaultMessageHandler;
import com.azure.spring.messaging.servicebus.core.ServiceBusTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class TestIntegration {

    private static final String OUTPUT_CHANNEL = "output";
    private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "myQueue";

    @Autowired
    private QueueOutboundGateway messagingGateway;

    public void send(String message) {
        this.messagingGateway.send(message);
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = OUTPUT_CHANNEL)
    public MessageHandler queueMessageSender(ServiceBusTemplate serviceBusTemplate) {
        serviceBusTemplate.setDefaultEntityType(ServiceBusEntityType.QUEUE);
        return new DefaultMessageHandler(QUEUE_NAME, serviceBusTemplate);
    }

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = OUTPUT_CHANNEL)
    public interface QueueOutboundGateway {
        void send(String text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `com.azure.spring.integration.core.handler.DefaultMessageHandler` supports a dynamic destination resolution from message headers:

```
private String toDestination(Message<?> message) {
    if (message.getHeaders().containsKey(AzureHeaders.NAME)) {
        return message.getHeaders().get(AzureHeaders.NAME, String.class);
    }

    return this.destination;
}
```

So, what you need is a `@Header(name = AzureHeaders.NAME) String destination` argument on your gateway's `send()` method. There is no reason in the dynamic nature for the `OUTPUT_CHANNEL`: only one gateway and one service activator for that `DefaultMessageHandler` is enough. You call `send()` with payload and target destination as params.

Comment: Got it. So the channel can be only one. I confess that even reading the documentation I have a little difficulty understanding how these channels work in practice.
But in fact your suggestion works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: But it doesn't support a dynamic ServiceBusTemplate yet?

Comment: I'm not sure what does that mean. What is dynamic `ServiceBusTemplate`? Doesn't look like it has some options to be based per message.

Comment: My idea was to be able to customize the connection-string and namespaceProperties on each send() call

Comment: Well, then probably you need your own `ServiceBusProducerFactory` implementation. The `DefaultServiceBusNamespaceProducerFactory` is based on a static configuration.